# How can I resolve this kind of error in jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

How can I resolve this kind of error in jsp page?

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
```

k, i understand ya, please answer my question?

the error was:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - The import javax.servlet cannot be  resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `Servlet-api.jar` in your `classpath` of your webapplication project. Please add this jar to your Classpath.

```
Multiple Annotations found at this line:
```

This happens sometimes when DOM validation happens in the editor for JSP files as well

Answer (score -1):

Please build your project with adding `servlet-api.jar` available in your `classpath` along with its `.tld` file.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple annotations found at this line: - 
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved.

if you use eclipse in case of add servlet-api.jar to javabuild path option
if you don't use any edtior then set the class path of servlet-api.jar

this type of error only for not found the required class so please add s**ervlet-api.jar** file

Comment: Your answer is very unclear, please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer